# change the select to his next value

Tags: jquery

Hi there
 I have a select, i need to change the value based on "+" and "-" buttons, as you can see it doesn't change his value
AddQta() should go to the next value
lessQta() should go to the previous value
i am stuck on it, and it doesnt give me any error

```js
   function AddQta()
        {
            $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlQta option:selected').next().val();
        }
        function LessQta()
        {
            $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlQta option:selected').prev().val();
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dialog" title="Quantita">

  <p>Seleziona quantita</p>
    <table>
        <tr><td rowspan="2">
         <select name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlQta" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlQta" style="font-size:Larger;height:25px;">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="0,5">0,5</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="2,5">2,5</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="3,5">3,5</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="4,5">4,5</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>

</select>
         </td>
            <td>
                   <input type=button value="+"  style="width: 25px; height: 20px" src="img/add.jpg"  OnClick="AddQta();" />                   
            </td>
            <td rowspan="2">
                 </td>                   
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> 
            <input type=button value="-"  style="width: 25px; height: 7px" src="img/less.jpg"  OnClick="LessQta();" />                   </td>

        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the assign the value

```js
   function AddQta()
        {
            var next = $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlQta option:selected').next().val();
            if(next)
                $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlQta').val(next);
        }
        function LessQta()
        {
            var prev = $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlQta option:selected').prev().val();
            if(prev)
                $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlQta').val(prev);
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dialog" title="Quantita">

  <p>Seleziona quantita</p>
    <table>
        <tr><td rowspan="2">
         <select name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlQta" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlQta" style="font-size:Larger;height:25px;">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="0,5">0,5</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="2,5">2,5</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="3,5">3,5</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="4,5">4,5</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>

</select>
         </td>
            <td>
                   <input type=button value="+"  style="width: 25px; height: 20px" src="img/add.jpg"  OnClick="AddQta();" />                   
            </td>
            <td rowspan="2">
                 </td>                   
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> 
            <input type=button value="-"  style="width: 25px; height: 7px" src="img/less.jpg"  OnClick="LessQta();" />                   </td>

        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems to get stuck when you go outside the values, like hit - on 1

Comment: I thought you are able to add some safety checks on your own. Nevertheless I have build you the completed code

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
var $current = $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlQta option:selected');
var $select = $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlQta');

function AddQta() {
  $current = $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlQta option:selected');
  $current.next().length > 0 ? $select.val($current.next().val()) : $select.val($select.find("option:first").val());
}

function LessQta() {
  $current = $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlQta option:selected');
  $current.prev().length > 0 ? $select.val($current.prev().val()) : $select.val($select.find("option:last").val());
}
```

This will allow that you will be returned to the first/last when you reach the beginning or end of your option.

Also the problem with your example `$('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlQta option:selected').next().val();` is that you are trying to get the value, since `.val()` is empty. If it was `.val(2)` then you are trying to set a value.

**Demo**

```js
var $current = $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlQta option:selected');
var $select = $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlQta');

function AddQta() {
  $current = $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlQta option:selected');
  $current.next().length > 0 ? $select.val($current.next().val()) : $select.val($select.find("option:first").val());
}

function LessQta() {
  $current = $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlQta option:selected');
  $current.prev().length > 0 ? $select.val($current.prev().val()) : $select.val($select.find("option:last").val());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dialog" title="Quantita">

  <p>Seleziona quantita</p>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">
        <select name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlQta" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlQta" style="font-size:Larger;height:25px;">
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="0,5">0,5</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="2,5">2,5</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="3,5">3,5</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="4,5">4,5</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>

        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type=button value="+" style="width: 25px; height: 20px" src="img/add.jpg" OnClick="AddQta();" />
      </td>
      <td rowspan="2">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type=button value="-" style="width: 25px; height: 20px" src="img/add.jpg" OnClick="LessQta();" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: based on your code starting from 1 and pushing + , it goes on 0,5, dont know how to fix this

Comment: @samee Its because your 0,5 comes after 1. just change the options order